# Generate array by traversing JSON JavaScript NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, fiware, fiware-orion

I am working with fiware and when making a subscriptions this information is being sent to a method that defined in my rest API, and I would like to save that information in my database.

The information that comes to me from the ContextBroker is:

```
{
  "subscriptionId": "5a268a598dc68904bbc7b3cf",
  "originator": "localhost",
  "contextResponses": [
    {
      "contextElement": {
        "type": "Temperature",
        "isPattern": "false",
        "id": "S_Temp001",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "name": "Tem_int",
            "type": "float",
            "value": 22,
            "metadatas": [
              {
                "name": "accuracy",
                "type": "Float",
                "value": 44}
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Tem_out",
            "type": "Integer",
            "value": 22
          }
        ]
      },
      "statusCode": {
        "code": "200",
        "reasonPhrase": "OK"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The method that I have defined in my API is this:

```
// insertBD
    function postinsertbdarduino1 (req, res) {

      var inver = {
        fiwareServicePath: String,
        entityId: String,
        entityType: String,
        attrName: String,
        attrType: String,
        attrValue: String,
        attrMd: String
      };

      var params = req.body;
      // check if the pass && name etc arrive and encrypt
        // Assign values ​​to the user object

        //inver.entityId = params.entityId;


        inver.fiwareServicePath = params.fiwareServicePath;
        inver.entityId = params.id;
        inver.entityType = params.type;
        inver.attrName = params.name;
            inver.attrType = params.attrType;
            inver.attrValue = params.attrValue;
            inver.attrMd = params.attrMd;

        pool.getConnection (function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
          console.log ('Error requesting a connection:' + err);
          return;
        }
        console.log ("connection tests");
        // if we want to add other conditions in the where would it be to put the fields and? and then to what is it equivalent
        // 'SELECT * FROM all WHERE id =? AND username =? ', [Req.params.id, user.username], function (err, rows)
        connection.query ('INSERT INTO inver SET?', [inver], function (err, rows) {
          if (err)
          {
            throw err;
            console.log ('Error when connecting' + error);
          }
          else
          {
            res.status (200) .json (rows);
          }
        });
        // so that it can be reused by the pool, it is important to "release" it
        connection.release ();
        });




    }
```

For now I'm just passing the id, the type and the name.

But he's saving my record in the empty database.

How can i fix this?

Thanks greetings.

**EDIT1**

I just launched the JSON I changed in my API method by the subscriptionId value `inver.entityId = params.subscriptionId;` and if the data arrives, but I need to recover the data `" type ":" Temperature "` `" id ":" S_Temp001 ",`

```
{
                 "name": "Tem_int",
                 "type": "float",
                 "value": 22,
                 "metadatas": [
                   {
                     "name": "accuracy",
                     "type": "Float",
                     "value": 44}
                 ]
               },

     {
                 "name": "Tem_out",
                 "type": "Integer",
                 "value": 22
               }
```

How can I get to that part of the JSON?

Thank you.

**EDIT2**

Good,

I modify the question.

How can I run this JSON in NODEJS JavaScript:

```
 {
       "subscriptionId": "5a268a598dc68904bbc7b3cf",
       "originator": "localhost",
       "contextResponses": [
         {
           "contextElement": {
             "type": "Temperature",
             "isPattern": "false",
             "id": "S_Temp001",
             "attributes": [
               {
                 "name": "Tem_int",
                 "type": "float",
                 "value": 2,
                 "metadatas": [
                   {
                     "name": "accuracy",
                     "type": "Float",
                     "value": 2}
                 ]
               },
               {
                 "name": "Tem_out",
                 "type": "Integer",
                 "value": 1
               }
             ]
           },
           "statusCode": {
             "code": "200",
             "reasonPhrase": "OK"
           }
         }
       ]
    }
```

Greetings and thank you.

**EDIT03**

Hello,

I need to generate the following format for my array.

```
var tmp = [['S_Temp001', 'Temperature', 'Tem_int', 'float', 2, 'accuracy',
'Float', 2], ['S_Temp001', 'Temperature', 'Tem_out', 'Integer', 1, 'accuracy',
'Float', 2]];

var tmp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < json["contextResponses"].length; i++) {

    tmp.push([json["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.id,
             json["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.type,
             json["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.attributes[0].name,
             json["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.attributes[0].type,
             json["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.attributes[0].value,
             json["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.attributes[0].metadatas[0].name,
             json["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.attributes[0].metadatas[0].type,
             json["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.attributes[0].metadatas[0].value]);
    console.log("tmp --> ",tmp);
    }
```

**EDIT04 solved**

Hi,

I have already found the solution, I add it in case it could be worth someone.

```
  var tmp2 = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < params.contextResponses.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes.length; j++) {
          for (var k = 0; k < params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas.length; k++) {
            console.log("nuevo log antes de petar: " + params["contextResponses"][i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].value);

            tmp2.push([params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.id,
                     params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.type,
                     params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].name,
                     params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].type,
                     params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].value,
                     params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].name,
                     params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].type,
                     params.contextResponses[i].contextElement.attributes[j].metadatas[k].value]);
            console.log("tmp2 --> ",tmp2);
          }
        }
    }
```

a greeting

Comment: `fiwareServicePath: String` is invalid Javascript (JS being loosely typed), I'm surprised your script runs at all.

Comment: It works correctly when you send a request from postman with this structure:

Format called orion

{
"fiwareServicePath": "46",
"entityId": "46",
"entityType": "46",
"attrName": "46",
"attrType": "46",
"attrValue": "46",
"attrMd": "46"

}

Comment: Not directly related with the topic of the question but... have you considered to use NGSIv2 subscriptions? The notification payload is easier to consume.

Comment: Hi, I'm using the V2 I created it like this:

{
  "description": "A subscription to get info about S_Temp001",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "id": "S_Temp001",
        "type": "Temperatura"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [
        "Tem_int"
      ]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://1xx.xxx.xxx:3790/api/postsus"
    },
    "attrs": [
      "Tem_int","Tem_out"
    ],
    "attrsFormat": "legacy"
  }
}